# Noob: Combining two Scripts

Tags: c#

First of all I have no clue what I am doing. I have two scripts that need to run in one location of a application we use. By themselves they run perfectly fine, but I don't know how to add them in the one field together.

**#1**

```
if (sd.IsNew)
    sd.Save(); //must save to get default GL Accounts, then they can be overwritten

if (sd.LineItems.Count(s => s.val_Is_Non_Inventory && !s.IsMarkedToDelete && !s.IsDeleted) > 0)

{
    SystemUser sysUser = new SystemUser(Framework.Controller.Credentials.UserName);

    foreach (SalesLineItem sli in sd.LineItems.Where(s => s.val_Is_Non_Inventory && !s.IsMarkedToDelete && !s.IsDeleted))
        sli.val_Sales_Account = Genframe4.Utils.ConvertToString(sysUser["xGL_Sales_Acct"]);
}

return String.Empty;
```

**#2**

```
if (sd.val_Sales_Doc_Type == "INVOICE" && sd.val_Misc_Charge != (decimal) sd.Customer["xHandlingFeeAmount"])
        sd["xOverrideFee"] = true;
    else
        sd["xOverrideFee"] = false;

    return "";
```

Comment: Is this an open-source or commercial ERP, or is it some kind of in-house product that you are scripting for?

Comment: What kind of errors are being produced? What goes wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by *"add them in one field together"*? Is the second one supposed to be part of the `foreach` of the first? How do you want to combine them?

Comment: It's a program based of devexpress. No errors, just no results. The program is a add for Dynamics GP called Salespad. Waiting for a response from them.

Comment: Often these programs have a lot of constraints in scripting. In my personal experience, I've usually had to receive specific instructions from the company itself due to the narrow range of knowledge involved - and sometimes the lack of documentation or knowledgeable users.

Comment: We need them to perform both the way both are written. Just dont know how a "and" statement works.

Comment: Well it was worth a try. I will keep exploring until I get a answer back from there.

Comment: Based on the documentation, it looks like you can indeed set the values of both fields. You have a single 'sd' object, as shown here: http://docs.salespad.net/support/desktop-support/entry/salespad-mobile/scripting

Comment: Could you try copying the if ... else ... statement from #2 without the return, and paste it before the return in #1, and then run it and let us know if it does what you want?

Answer (score 0):

In Salespad, a script is really just a C# event that is raised very much like a normal event - the difference being that the user enters the code rather than it being precompiled.

The function signature for the script looks like this:

`public string SalesDocumentPreSave(CancelEventArgs e, SalesPad.Bus.SalesDocument sd)` [See Documentation](http://docs.salespad.net/support/desktop-support/entry/salespad-mobile/scripting)

This gives the opportunity to update/manipulate the SalesDocument as necessary before finally returning a message.

In this particular case, you can combine the statements together, but only use a single return statement, as shown below:

```
if (sd.IsNew)
    sd.Save(); //must save to get default GL Accounts, then they can be overwritten

if (sd.LineItems.Count(s => s.val_Is_Non_Inventory && !s.IsMarkedToDelete && !s.IsDeleted) > 0)
{
    SystemUser sysUser = new SystemUser(Framework.Controller.Credentials.UserName);

    foreach (SalesLineItem sli in sd.LineItems.Where(s => s.val_Is_Non_Inventory && !s.IsMarkedToDelete && !s.IsDeleted))
        sli.val_Sales_Account = Genframe4.Utils.ConvertToString(sysUser["xGL_Sales_Acct"]);
}

if (sd.val_Sales_Doc_Type == "INVOICE" && sd.val_Misc_Charge != (decimal) sd.Customer["xHandlingFeeAmount"])
    sd["xOverrideFee"] = true;
else
    sd["xOverrideFee"] = false;

return String.Empty;
```

According the the documentation, this should work. Remember, though, that we do not have access to your environment or other scripts that might affect this. Be sure to test thoroughly.